# How to apply childs to before in css

Tags: html, css

I have four blocks where I specified before, in order to change the radius of the central block using before, the problem is that all my blocks are purple, I need to apply different colors for all blocks, for example blue, yellow, red, green, I guess what is needed use childs for this example, but I don't quite understand how to implement it

```css
.EnjoyGirlsContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.EnjoyGirlsList {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.EnjoyGirlsList div img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 304px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.EnjoyCardContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.EnjoyCardChildContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: purple;
}

.EnjoyCardChildContainer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 8px solid purple;
}

.EnjoyCardChildContainer:first-child:before {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}

.EnjoyCard {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.EnjoyCardChildContainer h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="EnjoyGirlsList">

  <div class="EnjoyCard">
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/A-Team-Logo.svg/1200px-A-Team-Logo.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
      <div class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="EnjoyCard">
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/A-Team-Logo.svg/1200px-A-Team-Logo.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
      <div class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="EnjoyCard">
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/A-Team-Logo.svg/1200px-A-Team-Logo.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
      <div class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="EnjoyCard">
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/A-Team-Logo.svg/1200px-A-Team-Logo.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
      <div class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What colours do you need to use? In what order? What - in your code - defines what colour should be used? Is it just the colour of the (currently) purple 'arrow' at the bottom you need to change?

Comment: As you can see, purple color is set for all four blocks, they are the same, I need to apply different colors for them

Comment: Yes, but that leads me to ask the same questions again: which colours? How does your code specify which colour should be used?

Comment: Use `:nth-child` to target them. For example, to select the third block `.EnjoyCard:nth-child(3) .EnjoyCardContainer`

Comment: Please show me a detailed example, I tried your version, but the background color does not change completely

Comment: You will also need to target `:before`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.EnjoyCard:nth-child(1) .EnjoyCardChildContainer:after {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(223, 8, 8, 0.967));
  border-top: 8px solid yellow;
}
```